# Negative short primitive has wrong value on Android 24

Tags: java, android, short

My Nexus 5X device running Android 7.0 (API level 24) has an extremely weird behavior when printing and comparing the values of `short` fields.

```
public class TestActivity {
    public class ShortWrapper {
        public short s;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        // Local short
        short s1 = -10;
        Log.d(TAG, "Local short (concatenation) = " + s1);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Local short (String.format) = %d", s1));
        if(s1 == -10) Log.d(TAG, "EQUAL"); else Log.d(TAG, "!!! NOT EQUAL !!!");

        // Short field
        TestActivity.ShortWrapper w = new TestActivity.ShortWrapper();
        w.s = -10;
        Log.d(TAG, "Short field (concatenation) = " + w.s);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Short field (String.format) = %d", w.s));
        if(w.s == -10) Log.d(TAG, "EQUAL"); else Log.d(TAG, "!!! NOT EQUAL !!!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Local short (concatenation) = -10
Local short (String.format) = -10
EQUAL
Short field (concatenation) = 65526         <<<<<<<<< ???
Short field (String.format) = -10
!!! NOT EQUAL !!!                           <<<<<<<<< ???
```

On another Android device running Android 4.4, and on an Android 7.0 emulator, the output is different, i.e. as expected.

**Why is the Nexus 5X dealing so weirdly with this negative short field?
Is this a bug of the platform or device ?**

Comment: `WelcomeActivity.ShortWrapper` that is not the same class as represented in your code snippet. Is the definition the same?

Comment: @Knossos Sorry about this, this was a typo. The snippet is now correct.

Comment: Looks like a JIT but with sign extension.

Comment: Note: `-10`, stored as '2-complement' in a variable `short` (16 bits) looks like: `1111111111110110`. This binary data, if evaluated as an *unsigned* integer, equals `65526`. This is probably what happens in my case. But why??

Comment: Note2: I ran the same code with a `byte` field instead of a `short`. The concatenation log triggers the same bug (wrong value, `246)`. The "String.format" call crashes the VM! `D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM`

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a bug in the VM on my device. I created an issue, but no one from Google has looked at it after a month: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225483

Comment: The bug has been closed by Google without investigation. I guess we'll never know what happened there.