# Strange issue with java 'short' precision in Android (only some API versions!)

Tags: java, android, bit, short

I have the following code snippet, which I call using isAvailable(0)

```
public short working_city_id;

public boolean isAvailable(int city_id)
{
  return working_city_id == city_id || working_city_id == -1;
}
```

This returns false on some platforms, and true on others, when working_city_id is set to 0.

I added debug statements like this

```
public boolean isAvailable(int city_id)
{
  System.out.println("CITY ID: " + city_id);
  System.out.println("WORKING CITY ID: " + working_city_id);

  return working_city_id == city_id || working_city_id == -1;
}
```

On most platforms (including emulated API 22 and API 24), it correctly outputs (and returns true)

```
I/System.out: CITY ID: 0
I/System.out: WORKING CITY ID: 0
```

However, on my emulated API 19 and API 16 versions, it outputs (and returns false)

```
I/System.out: CITY ID: 0
I/System.out: WORKING CITY ID: -65536
```

How is this even possible? -65536 is out of the possible valid range of short values (-32768 to +32767), and in fact is exactly -(2^16), which suggests some kind of wrapping issue, since it is (if I'm not mistaken) bitwise equivalent to zero in 16-bit precision!?

And as stated, it only happens on certain API emulator versions. Has anyone seen this before, or can explain it?

Thanks!

*** EDIT***

I changed the code again, to *FORCE* a conversion back to short precision, and now the code works on all platforms.

```
public boolean isAvailable(int city_id)
{
  System.out.println("CITY ID: " + city_id);
  System.out.println("WORKING CITY ID: " + working_city_id);

  int temp = working_city_id;
  System.out.println("TEMP: " + temp);

  working_city_id = (short) temp;
  System.out.println("NEW WORKING CITY ID: " + working_city_id);

  return working_city_id == city_id || working_city_id == -1;
}
```

The output (on the platforms exhibiting the strange behaviour) is

```
I/System.out: CITY ID: 0
I/System.out: WORKING CITY ID: -65536
I/System.out: TEMP: -65536
I/System.out: NEW WORKING CITY ID: 0
```

Weird (but at least it works). I simply don't understand how that -65536 is getting into a short-precision variable in the first place though!?

Especially since, in this workaround, forcibly reassigning -65536 into the short-precision variable yields 0

Comment: Maybe you need to initialize working_city_id

Comment: I think there's more going on here than what we can see with the posted code.  Could you provide a full, working example where you call isAvailable that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Hi Michael, I'll see if I can isolate the problem more, but its completely repeatable by running the application (and also repeatably works in some versions but not others). The key issue for me is this - how is it possible to have -65536 in a short-precision variable!? This is supposed to be impossible in java!?

Comment: I agree with you, Java shorts are 16 bit signed values with an inclusive range of -32768 to 32767.  So, something else must be going on here.  Maybe with the compiler converting from one type to another when doing string concatenation?

Comment: Hi Michael, its not just the string concatenation though, since the comparison on the last line is also returning a different value depending on the platform (and -65536 in 16 bits is exactly the same as zero... ie 16 0s, which is very suspicious)

Comment: OK - but there is another potential problem as == and || operators have the same precedence and are evaluated from left to right.  Is this what you intended?  Maybe parens might clarify the problem.

Comment: Hi Michael, || operator on shorts and ints has no meaning, so I'm confident that line is correct. And indeed, on the platforms that are not showing the weird short value, that line is behaving as intended.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104963/negative-short-primitive-has-wrong-value-on-android-24

Comment: My advice would be to not use `short`.

Comment: Hi, Weston, thanks for that related link, good to know that I'm not imagining this problem! Unfortunately, I'm trying to limit memory footprint, so am making heavy use of smaller primitives like byte and short. These are fundamental and well-defined Java data types, so it's a little bit scary that Android doesn't seem to handle them correctly!